# What is the general signature of a function in python 3.8 or 3.8+?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have not been able to find a good place that I can refer to to help myself understand a general function signature in python 3.8 or +. I want to understand a general syntax that includes position only, keywords only, *args, **kwargs and all.

I am able to reason about everything but I cannot seem to fir *args into the general signature.

```
def inc(a:int, b:int,/, c:int=10, d:int=5, *, e:int=15,f:int=3, **kwargs) -> int:
     return None
```

In this no matter where I place *args it throws a syntax error. I can remove `,*,` (the keyword-only-after-this indicator) and then *args seems to fit in nicely

Can you please help me understand how *args fit in with position only and keywords only elements of a function signature and what a general syntax for a python function is supposed to look like

Comment: You have a narrow, specific problem -- asking an unnecessarily general question moves away from compliance with topicality guidelines.

Comment: My problem is a lack of understanding as well. I did not know the interplay between various elements of a general function signature. What improvements do you suggest i could have had in formulating my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use both a varargs argument and the special `*` argument to indicate keyword-only arguments after positional arguments. [PEP-3102](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/), which introduced the keyword-only syntax, says:

> The second syntactical change is to allow the argument name to be omitted for a varargs argument. The meaning of this is to allow for keyword-only arguments for functions that would **not otherwise take a varargs argument**.

(emphasis mine).

You can either have `*` or `*args`, but not both. The point of the special `*` argument is to allow you to have keyword-only arguments when you don't already have a varargs argument.

Comment: This is incorrect - you've misread the source you're quoting. You can have both varargs and keyword-only arguments. For example, in `def f(*args, x)`, `f` takes varargs and `x` is keyword-only.

Comment: What I'm saying is you can't have both `*args` and `*`.

Comment: But the first line of your answer is "You can't use both a varargs argument and keyword-only arguments", which is false. You can use varargs and keyword-only arguments in the same function. `def f(*args, x): ...` is an example.

Answer (score 2):

`*` is not "the keyword-only-after-this indicator". Non-`**` arguments listed after a `*` argument are keyword-only. For example, in the following function:

```
def f(*args, x):
    ...
```

`x` is keyword-only.

If you don't *want* your function to take `*args`, you can use a bare `*` to mark the start of keyword-only arguments, but if you do want `*args`, then keyword-only arguments go after that.